# Using AnyOrigin for cross-domain queries

Tags: jquery

How do I use [anyorigin.com](http://anyorigin.com) to query cross domain?

Currently my code is ([Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FAYj3/)):

```
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.google.com&callback=?', function(data){
    alert(data.title); // get title of site
});
```

`data.title` is returned as `undefined`. How do I get the `<title>` attribute of the site I send to anyorigin.com? What's the syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.google.com&callback=?', function(data){
    var siteContents = data.contents;    
    alert((/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(siteContents)[1]);
});
```

**​OUTPUT:-**

```
Google
```